# What is the use of docker container's shm mounted on to the host in docker v18.09

Tags: docker

After bringing up a test container on docker v18.09, I see this in 'df -h' on the node running docker container:

```
shm 64M 0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/7b362d4438678b2e07c08d17e61d813dc85e2e49d1540c87e7c1ebe470052b95/mounts/shm
```

Could not find any information on why this is needed? what is the use of it?

Is there any way to disable this feature?